# Using roc() in R with a parametric response variable name in the formula

Tags: r, roc

I have a column named `inp`, and 10 columns named `resp1, ..., resp10` in a matrix in R, and I want to compute receiver operating characteristic `roc()` using `inp` as input variable and each of `resp1, ..., resp10` as a response variable.

```
g <- roc(resp1 ~ inp, data = mat)
```

How can I run this call in a loop with index `n=1..10` where i can use `resp_n` as a response variable each time? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want a formula:

```
g <- lapply(1:10, function(x) {
    roc(as.formula(paste0("resp", x, " ~ inp"), data=mat)
})
```

But you can do it more easily with standard extraction like this:

```
g <- lapply(1:10, function(x) {
    var <- paste0("resp", x)
    roc(mat[["inp"]], mat[[var]])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lapply function like this:

g<-lapply(c(res1, res2, ..., res10), function(x){roc(x~inp, data=mat)})

The class of 'g' will be a list.

Comment: I don't think you can use `c(res1, res2, ..., res10)` in `lapply` because `res1` is not a variable name, it is the name of the column in the data matrix.

Comment: You can pass it as character and turn it back into a formula later

Comment: Yes, I think this is the best way to do that. Thanks for letting know "as.formula" method, I did not know that before.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see. I just forgot something. You can use c(resp1, resp2, ..., resp10) in lapply but you've to add the option 'get' like this:

**g<-lapply(c(resp1, resp2, ..., resp10), function(x){
   res<-roc(get(x)~inp, data=mat)
   return(res) })**

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work, either, unfortunately. I get the error "object 'resp1' not found" since it is not a variable name. I will go with as.formula() which converts a string to a formula.